# Android SearchView widget wont start searchableActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, searchview

I'm actually trying to perform a search from a fragment. I would just like to display the text (with a Toast) the user is trying to search with the SearchView widget which in inflated to the fragment. According to the Android documentation, when a user performs a search with the SearchView widget, the application should start a SearchableActivity. The problem is that I can't make it start a SearchableActivity.

Here is my Android Manifest (EDITED with Berhan zikarge's answer):

```
        <activity
        android:name=".ClientActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_client"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan">

        <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".SearchableActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SearchableActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
        </activity>
```

Here is the fragment called in ClientActivity :

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_organisation_search, container, false);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) view.findViewById(R.id.search_view_id);
        searchView.setIconified(false);
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        searchView.requestFocus();
        return view;
    }
```

The layout it inflates :

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view_id"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hint="@string/search_hint"
        android:background="@drawable/block"
        >

    </android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>


</ScrollView>
```

The SearchableActivity.java :

```
public class SearchableActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            doMySearch(query);
        }

    }
    //Here no log is displayed in logcat, and no Toast is shown on the app
    public void doMySearch(String query) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), query+"wsh", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("The query : ",query);

    }
}
```

I've been strugling on this problem for more then 2 hours, if anyone have a solution I would be thankful.

**EDIT** 
I made it work adding this code to my fragment :

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put the meta-data tags on the activity sending the search data and not the one receiving the data. ClientActivity should have the meta-data tag:

```
<!-- this activity enables the search dialog to initiate searches
     in the SearchableActivity -->
<activity android:name=".OtherActivity" ... >
    <!-- enable the search dialog to send searches to SearchableActivity -->
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
               android:value=".SearchableActivity" />
</activity>
...
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

Comment: I did, but the ".OtherAcitivty" is called ".ClientActivity".

Comment: Your XML shows the tag outside the activity tag for ClientActivity.

Comment: I am sorry, I made a mistake copying/pasting to create that post. I edited that.

Comment: Do you have any log statements to see how far you get in the search process?

Comment: There are no special log, it seems like the SearchActivity never get started.

Answer (score 0):

**the problem is that the meta data for the client activity is outside of the      activity tag. copy and paste the following code in the manifest**

```
 <activity
    android:name=".ClientActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_client"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan">
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
        android:value=".SearchableActivity" />
    </activity>

     <activity android:name=".SearchableActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>
```

Comment: I am sorry I made a mistake copy/pasting to create that post. I just copied/pasted the XML you posted, and it still doesn't work.